Series of $(z-1)^{3/2}$ around $z=0$?
I would like to expand $(z-1)^{3/2}$ around $z=0$ where $z$ is a complex variable. If I naively take the derivatives with respect to $z$ and evaluate at $z=0\thinspace$, I find:
$$
(z-1)^{3/2} = -i + \frac{3i}{2}z - \frac{3i}{8}z^2 + O(z^3)
$$
However, if I ask Mathematica for the series expansion, the sign of the series depends on the imaginary part of $z$. Specifically, I obtain:
$$
(z-1)^{3/2} =\begin{cases}
 -i+\frac{3 i z}{2}-\frac{3 i z^2}{8}+O\left(z^3\right), & \mathrm{Im}(z)\geq 0 \\
 i-\frac{3 i z}{2}+\frac{3 i z^2}{8}+O\left(z^3\right), & \text{Otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$
Can anyone help me understand this? Why does the sign of the imaginary part matter when expanding around $z=0$?

It is probably using the principal branch, which as you know is discontinuous across the negative real axis. However there does exist a holomorphic branch (just not the principal one); do you see why?

No, I am not really sure why or how. I thought about writing $z-1=re^{i\phi}$ to get $r^{3/2}e^{i3\phi/2}$, and then let $r$ tend to zero. In this case, I can see that it makes a difference if we are in the upper or lower complex plane as we get towards $r=0$, but not sure what to make of it.

Its about $$z\to (z-1)\sqrt{z-1},$$ that by convention has its branch cut along $$z\in\left(-\infty,1\right).$$ So by a series expansion at z=0 just on the cut, the two formal series from below or from above are taken, that both converge in the unit disk because of the branch point at z=1.
Of course one can define $$z\to\sqrt z $$ with argument $\phi \in (0,2 \pi)$ with a branch cut along just below the positive axis $z\in (1,\infty)$.
Then  $\sqrt(-1)=i$ without double signs. This $\sqrt{}$ maps the plane to the upper half plane, often the better choice in practical problems.

Thank you for the answer. I am not sure fully understand. The first branch cut makes sense to me. This is also what I see when plotting the Riemann surface. But what exactly does it mean that I can define my own branch cut? I need two expansions of the function. One for $z>>1$, which is simple enough, and one for $z<<1$. I am confused about the latter because I do not know which sign to choose.

The branch cut is a line of discontinuity from the branch point to complex $\infty$ along any smooth curve. Complex $\infty$ is consided a point with neighborhoods the outer of circles. The closed complex plane is a smooth 1-1 map of the 2-sphere, as such a curve connecting a finite point, shifted to the south pole, to the north pole represents a date line with a jump of $2 \pi$ in global time aka angle.
Near the cut line at $z=0$ the series are the an integral of $$-\frac{1}{1-z}= -\sum z^n, \ |z<1|$$. The antiderivative is $$\log(1-z)= \sum \frac{z^n}{n}, \ |z|<1$$ plus a free constant.
